# What is replacement in Java-17 for Java-8 built in external dependency path- jdk8/jre/lib/ext/external-dependency.jar

Tags: java, java-8, java-17

I am migrating from Java 8 to Java17 and I have 1 external dependency jar which was directly placed in jdk8/jre/lib/ext location in Java 8 but in Java 17 there is no such path available for external library. so, I tried below script in Java 17,
`java -classpath "my_path/abc.jar" -jar my_path/myapp.jar`

Where,
abc.jar is external dependency jar
myapp.jar is main application jar

But above script didn't work. How to make it work?

I tried below script in Java 17,
`java -classpath "my_path/abc.jar" -jar my_path/myapp.jar`
But it didn't work.

Comment: Is `my_path` an absolute path?  Are you certain abc.jar is present in that directory?

Comment: The extension mechanism has been removed since Java 9. For any external jar files, you have to specify them in the class path. What are the errors are you getting?

Comment: You can't mix `-jar` with `-classpath`. You need `java -classpath my_path/abc.jar:my_path /myapp.jar a.b.c.Main`

Comment: @g00se you can also add a [Class-Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html) header field in the JAR manifest.

Comment: You can, but personally I don't like it as it's hidden and easy to break

Comment: @g00se your fix is working with windows(by replacing ':' with ';') but not working with Linux terminal. Any suggestions?

Comment: That really [has no meaning](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors)

Comment: Hi@g00se, it worked, it was path issue. I think in Linux terminal if we are giving absolute path then we can directly use ':' w/o quotes and if it is relative path or both jars are present current path then we have to specify like abc.jar".;myapp.jar" a.b.c.Main. Thanks !

Comment: Hi @VGR , it's absolute path. Thanks!

Comment: *I think in Linux terminal if we are giving absolute path then we can directly use ':' w/o quotes and if it is relative path or both jars are present current path then we have to specify like abc.jar".;myapp.jar" a.b.c.Main.* No. It's really quite simple: **a** the quotes are for paths containing spaces and **b** the path separator on Unix-based systems is `:`. I'm finding it difficult to know if you *still* have a problem or not, and if you do, what it is..?

Comment: Hi @g00se , Actually my application main jar name is dynamic e.g. myapp_version_number.jar So I am trying -classpath my_path/abc.jar:/my_path/myapp*.jar a.b.c.Main but it's not working

Comment: That really has [no meaning](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/17-errors) But you need to try something like: `dynajar=my_path/myapp*.jar;java -classpath "my_path/abc.jar:/$dynajar" a.b.c.Main` And you need to make sure that can only expand *to ONE file*

Comment: Were you to ensure you built with a name like `jar-2023-08-22.jar` you could sort and get the latest

Comment: Hi @g00se, it worked with command substitution in Linux bash, main_app=$(echo /my_path/my_app-*.jar) 
                                                          java -classpath /my_path/abc.jar:${main_app} a.b.c.Main

Comment: Yes, but see what I wrote earlier. The `echo` in yours is redundant

Comment: @g00se it's not working without 'echo'.

Comment: It should do. You're probably quoting it